# Highscore Popup If New

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I want to implement a simple concept. If the player gets a new highscore, there will be a sprite `newHS` that will become `visible`, otherwise it is hidden. Here is my code:

```
if (score < highScore) {
        newHS.visible = NO;
    }

else {
        highScore = score;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        newHS.visible = YES;
    }
```

However, I ran into a problem. If I start off by scoring 1, it pops up just fine. Then if I score 1 again it still pops up (because score is not less than highScore, it's the same), but I don’t want that because it’s not a NEW highscore anymore.. How would I get around this? I thought of adding another variable, something like “previousScore” or something but I am not sure how to approach this..

Comment: maybe try: `if(score <= highScore)` instead of `if(score < highScore)`

Comment: I’ve tried that and that doesn’t work because, technically everytime you get a new highscore, score==highscore. For example, on the first time ever playing, score = 0 and highscore = 0. Then if you get 3 for example, highscore and score are both 3 so the NEW wouldn’t pop up even though you got a new highscore..

Comment: but if you score 3 and 3 is the highscore technically you didn't just get a new highscore.. just saying

Comment: So to clarify you only want your new highscore scene to show if theres a NEW highscore?

Comment: Exactly. I want to show it only if it is NEW. My example above was saying that if you get 3 the first time around, it is a NEW highscore, so it works. But if you get 3 again, it is NOT a NEW highscore, but it still shows the highscore scene since the ELSE statement is being ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int highscore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"HighScore"];

if (score > highscore) {
    newHS.visible = YES;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"HighScore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else newHS.visible = NO;
```

You don't show us how or where you create the `highscore integer`, my guess is that you create a new local `highscore` int and set it to `0` instead of set it to the saved `highscore`.

Comment: I did have int highscore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"HighScore"]; but I had that in my init method for my game scene rather than gameOver scene. With your above code it seems to be working! Quick question, you have setInteger:score, shouldn't that be setInteger:highscore, or no?

Comment: Also why don't I need highscore = score; anymore?

Comment: It is exactly the same thing to set score as new hightscore instead of  score = highscore but i personally prefer it because it takes less space.

Comment: If you chose to use my code than every time highscore will get a new value which will be the last highscore, so assigning something to highscore will only take space.

Comment: Also it seems that your highscore integer is a global variable. You can remove it and only use it locally.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying that! Also, I just removed the global variable and made it local.

Comment: I just noticed that it isn't working still with your code. The highscore is always the LAST highscore I had.. For example, if I score 2 it says Score = 2, Highscore = 0, then if I score 5, it says Score = 5, Highscore = 2, etc..

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the problem with your code. The problem I was having was with my functions. Thanks again!